# Find rectangle in pdf using iText 7

Tags: pdf, itext, itext7

I've used foxit to create a pdf and then added a shape (rectangle) to the pdf.
[image]
[image]

I'm using the ILocationExtractionStrategy in order to locate the shape.

```
            using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName))
            {
                using (PdfDocument docToSign = new PdfDocument(pdfReader))
                {
                    var sf = new ShapeFilter();
                    new PdfCanvasProcessor(sf).ProcessPageContent(docToSign.GetFirstPage());
                }
            }

//ILocationExtractionStrategy implementation
    public class ShapeFilter : ILocationExtractionStrategy
    {
        public void EventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(type);
        }

        public ICollection<IPdfTextLocation> GetResultantLocations()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public ICollection<EventType> GetSupportedEvents()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

For my simple test document which only contains one rectangle, ILocationExtractionStrategy.EventOccurred is called three times (CLIP_PATH_CHANGED,RENDER_PATH,CLIP_PATH_CHANGED), but i'm unable to find the position of the shape.

I've used RUPS to check what property i should look for, but even there i cant find the rectangle.
[image]

The pdf can be downloaded from onedrive: https://1drv.ms/b/s!AkROTDoCWFJnlrZOPiV74h3456Trwg

Any hints how such a rectangle(the position of it) can be read using iText?

Comment: You only write the `EventType type`; have you considered looking into the `IEventData data`? That's where you'll find the data.

Comment: Should i look for it in ClippingPathInfo or PathRenderInfo? And is there a proper rectangle or do i just get a bunch of paths and must figure it out myself?

Comment: *"Should i look for it in ClippingPathInfo or PathRenderInfo?"* - That depends on how a given rectangle is drawn. If its outlines are defined as clip path and then an arbitrarily large area is filled, the ClippingPathInfo is more important. If the rectangle is drawn as a filled or stroked path, the PathRenderInfo is more important. For a generic solution you need to consider both, maybe even in combination.

Comment: *"And is there a proper rectangle or do i just get a bunch of paths and must figure it out myself?"* - Most likely you get a collection of MoveTos and LineTos.

Comment: In the case at hand it's a stroked path, so you have to look into the PathRenderInfo.